# How to decode multiple images barcode with opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I can read the code for each image but when the image is finished I don't press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the window and with this code how do I decode multiple images in the folder at the same time?

These are my codes

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

paths = r'\QrCodeBarCode\Images'
#img = cv2.imread('1.png')
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# cap.set(3,640)
# cap.set(4,480)

for img in paths:
    while True:

        # success, img = cap.read()
        for barcode in decode(img):
            myData = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
            print(myData)
            pts = np.array([barcode.polygon],np.int32)
            pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
            cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(255,0,255),5)
            pts2 = barcode.rect
            cv2.putText(img,myData,(pts2[0],pts2[1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.9,(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.imshow('Result',img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Could you save the images to files instead of using cv2.imshow? Try `with open(filename, 'wb') as openfile: openfile.write(imagebytes...)`

Comment: You could also use the progressbar library to show the program's progress. https://pypi.org/project/progressbar2/

Comment: I want the above code to work wide for multiple images at once

Comment: Do you need to see the images immediately? or can you save them to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Read all data in the direcory using `os.listdir` then check each image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

paths = r'\QrCodeBarCode\Images'

for filename in os.listdir(paths):
    img_path = os.path.join(paths, filename)
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    for barcode in decode(img):
        myData = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
        print(myData)
        pts = np.array([barcode.polygon],np.int32)
        pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
        cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(255,0,255),5)
        pts2 = barcode.rect
        cv2.putText(img,myData,(pts2[0],pts2[1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    0.9,(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.imwrite('result_' + filename, img)
```